# Toggle switch / T-Flip Flip

Tags: ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-3, logic

I am having trouble trying to apply a flip-flop to the following scenario. Say I have the following array:

```
[ 'on',
  'random text',
  'random text',
  'random text',
  'random text',
  'off'
  'random text',
  'random text',
  'on'
  'random text',
  'off'
  'random text',
  'random text',
   etc...
```

I want a switch to flip according to one of two values (as represented by 'on' and 'off' in the array)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: *"I have no way of determining a value to trigger true/true as the text will always be random."* Please expand and explain what you mean by that.

Comment: with the ruby flip flop, you can perform this action where both conditions are met one after the other, but they are triggered by a specific value (apologies if I am not explaining well, see example here: http://nithinbekal.com/posts/ruby-flip-flop/)

Comment: That explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your data here is a simple flip-flop example.

```
x = [ 'on',
  'random text',
  'random text',
  'random text',
  'random text',
  'off',
  'random text',
  'random text',
  'on',
  'random text',
  'off',
  'random text',
  'random text'
]

x.each do |text|
  if text['on'] .. text['off']
    puts text
  end
end

#on
#random text
#random text
#random text
#random text
#off
#on
#random text
#off
```